# Apache camel filter records based on a list stored in caffeine-cache

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, caffeine-cache

I have 2 routes which intends to filter user's messages coming from kafka based on a blacklist of user's ids stored in caffeine cache.

The first route that *loads a txt file containing ids of blacklisted users at startup*, is defined as follow :

```
from(file(...))
        .id(getRouteId())
        .split().tokenize("\n")
            .stopOnException()
            .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
            .completionTimeout(500)
        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_PUT))
        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY, constant("blacklistedIds"))
        .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "blacklistedIds")
```

Note: the blacklist consist of a `List<String> blacklistedIds` and it's stored in caffeine cache (which get initialised at startup of the application).

The second route which get user's messages from kafka (`User properties : id,firstname,lastname`), and it's defined as follow:

```
from(kafka(...))
        .id(getRouteId())
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, UserMessage.class)
        // filter here (based on cache) to only let go authorized users
        //.filter(method(UserMessageFilterService.class, "isAuthorizedUser"))
        .to(output())
```

My question is how can I do to filter the incoming message by using the blacklistIds stored in caffeine cache ? How can I get the cache in `UserMessageFilterService#isAuthorizedUser` bean's method ? Is there a better/simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the message body and arbitrary headers to `isAuthorizedUser()`

```java
from(kafka(...))
    ...
    // save the UserMessage in a header
    .setHeader("userMessage", body())

    // retrieve the cached list of blacklisted Ids
    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.CamelCaffeineAction, CaffeineConstants.GET)
    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.CamelCaffeineKey, constant("blacklistedIds"))
    .to("caffeine-cache:blacklistedIds)

    .filter(method(UserMessageFilterService.class, "isAuthorizedUser"))
    
    // restore the original body
    .setBody(header("userMessage"))
```

UserMessageFilterService.java

```java
public boolean isAuthorizedUser(List<String> blacklistedIds, @Header("userMessage") UserMessage userMessage) {
    return !blacklistedIds.contains(userMessage.getUserId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy but this sounds to me as a work around, I can't use `enrich` to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, enrich is a fine choice. You can use an aggregator to combine the user data with the auth result.